# Backbone: Unable to override constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, web, marionette

I'm trying to override Backbone.Model constructor with my own, in order to be able to pass my parameters from outside and not as a created-object.

here is my code:

```
 var Video = Backbone.Model.extend({

constructor : function (videoUrl,imageSource,title,rating,description,starsImageSource){
    this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
    this.imageSource = imageSource;
    this.title = title;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.description = description;
    this.starsImageSource = starsImageSource;
    Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
    }   

});
```

when trying to enter

```
new Video("www.yahoo","coins.jpg","Yahoo",4,"hhhh","5stars.png")
```

the following error appear:
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj
here is my includes:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://marionettejs.com/downloads/backbone.marionette.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

thanks!

Comment: `Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments)` is invalid. You have to use prototype of Backbone.Model `constructor`

Comment: BTW: Why you don't use `initialize` method? It allows to pass/receive parameters too

Comment: (1) What's wrong with using named attributes when building a Backbone model? (2) None of those object properties will be model attributes so none of the usual model things will be aware of them, why use a Backbone model at all in this case? (3) What do you expect the standard constructor to do with an `arguments` that doesn't look anything like what it is expecting to see? What you're trying to doesn't make much sense in a Backbone context.

Comment: @user3613500 `Backbone.Model.prototype.apply`. But you rather to use `initialize` method. Overriding constructor is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You have two things to correct:

1. As mentioned before, prefer `initialize` over `constructor`
2. Follow the API of `new Model(attributes, options)`. The reason is backbone will take your first argument and treat is as as an attributes hash. in case its not an object, it may have unexpected behavior. In this case you may have something like:

```js
var Video = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize : function (attrs, options){
    _.extend(this, _.pick(options, 'videoUrl', 'imageSource', 'title', 'rating', 'description', 'starsImageSource'));
  }
});

new Video(null, {
  videoUrl:"www.yahoo",
  imageSource: "coins.jpg",
  title: "Yahoo",
  rating: 4,
  description: "hhhh",
  starsImageSource: "5stars.png"
});
```

One question would be: why do you want to assign these parameters as first class parameters on the model object, and not as model attributes? In this case you don't need to add a constructor, just to pass the data:

```js
new Video({
  videoUrl:"www.yahoo",
  imageSource: "coins.jpg",
  title: "Yahoo",
  rating: 4,
  description: "hhhh",
  starsImageSource: "5stars.png"
});
```

Comment: thank you very much. I want to achieve some sort of polymorphism , I'd like to inherit from Video , then , the subclass will only get the URL , and it will now to get and parse all the other fields just from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to override `constructor`.

The following code does exactly the same you need:

```
var Video = Backbone.Model.extend({

initialize : function (videoUrl,imageSource,title,rating,description,starsImageSource){
    this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
    this.imageSource = imageSource;
    this.title = title;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.description = description;
    this.starsImageSource = starsImageSource;
}   

});
```